# Error writing parquet file in s3 with Pyspark

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-emr

I'm trying to read some tables(parquet files) and do some joins and write them as parquet format in S3 but I'm getting an error or taking more than a couple of hours to write the table.

error:

```
    An error was encountered:
    Invalid status code '400' from https://.... with error payload: {"msg":"requirement failed: session isn't active."}
```

I am able to write other tables as a parquet except for that table.

This is my sample code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.sql.catalogImplementation", "in-memory").getOrCreate()

table1 = spark.read.parquet("s3://.../table1")
table1.createOrReplaceTempView("table1")

table2 = spark.read.parquet("s3://.../table2")
table2.createOrReplaceTempView("table2")

table3 = spark.read.parquet("s3://.../table3")
table3.createOrReplaceTempView("table3")

table4 = spark.read.parquet("s3://.../table4")
table4.createOrReplaceTempView("table4")

Final_table = spark.sql("""
select
      a.col1
      a.col2
...
      d.coln
 from

        table1 a
        left outer join
        table2 b
        on
        cond1
        cond2
        cond3
        left outer join
        table3 c
        on
...
        """)

Final_table.count()
# 3813731240

output_file="s3://.../final_table/"

final_table.write.option("partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic").mode('overwrite').partitionBy("col1").parquet(output_file)
```

Just to add more, I've tried repartition but didn't work. Also, I've tried with different EMR clusters such as
Cluster1:
Master
m5.24xlarge

Cluster2:
Master
m5.24xlarge
1 core
m5.24xlarge

Cluster3:
Master
m5d.2xlarge
8 cores
m5d.2xlarge

EMR release version
5.29.0

Comment: How are you submitting your job to EMR?

Comment: @srikanthholur I'm using jupyter notebook in EMR but also I've tried spark-submit.

Comment: Set this property and see if fixes the issue. `("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval","3600s")`

Comment: @srikanthholur no still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Most spark jobs can be optimized by visualizing their DAG.

In this scenario if you are able to run the sql and get the count in minimum time and all your time is consumed just for writing then here are some suggestions

1. Since you already know the count of your dataframe, remove the count operation as it is unnecessary overhead for your job.
2. Now you are partitioning your data based on col1, so better try repartitioning your data so that the least shuffle is performed at the time of writing.

You can do something like

```
df.repartition('col1', 100).write
```

Also you can set the number based on the partition count if you know it.